# Program that was working yesterday is giving me a connect ETIMEOUT error

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I wrote a simple program in js that's only goal was to connect to my aws server so that i could add on functions to update certain fields in the server. After attempting to get import statements to work I am now receiving error connecting: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT every time i try and run the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated because I am at a loss.

My program is

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');


const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host:'******',
  user:'*****',
  password:'*****',
  database:'*****'
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected!');
});
```

Comment: where are you running this? Please give more detail on setup

Comment: @mokugo-devops im running this on vs code windows

Comment: And the MySQL DB? Is any of this running in AWS? :)

Comment: The MySQL DB is running in AWS i am attempting to write a program that updates user info but now i believe there is an overall problem with my vscode.

Comment: OK, well AWS wise can you check the security group for your database is allowing inbound access of your IP address. Give it all a double check :)

Comment: I can check but my coworkers can access the server just fine so I think the issue is more on my end:(